# Angular custom library component only rendering in app.component

Tags: angular

I am trying to import my custom library from a different project into my new application. As of now I have the library developed and am using `npm link` to import it into my app locally. I am seeing this strange phenomena. My app.component is set up like many apps and has a router-outlet in it:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have created a local component that uses my custom library component (this is the template):

```html
<my-custom-lib-component></my-custom-lib-component>
```

and a route definition that points to that component like thus:

```js
const routes = [{
  path: 'local-path',
  component: LocalComponent
}];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

When you navigate to `local-path` the custom library component doesn't render in the dom. The tags for `my-custom-lib-component` are there, but the component doesn't get built. Other angular directives and components work.

However if I move the library component to my app component, it renders. I have never encountered anything like this before.

Why would my library component render in the app.component and not in a component created by a router outlet?

Comment: Are you importing that library in the module where you have declared the newly created component?

Comment: I just figured it out. For some reason the component wasn't declared in the the app.module, which is weird because 1) I used the angular cli to create it 3) It didn't give me any errors that it wasn't declared and 3) The component loaded

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. For some reason the component wasn't declared in the the app.module, which is weird because 1) I used the angular cli to create it 2) I only have one module in my app, 3) It didn't give me any errors that it wasn't declared and 4) the component loaded and partially worked